# Can I set ical4j VEvent ID to UUID?

Tags: java, icalendar, ical4j

I'm trying to create an ics file using ical4j version 3.2.14.

The calendar events are based on items I have in a database with a UUID as the primary key. if the date of one of the events changes based on the database changing, I want google calendar (or others that use the ics file from a url) to know to move the correct date. If I can't do that is there a better way to do it without having to keep track of the UIDs ical4j creates?

So far I haven't been able to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out right after posting the question.

```
Property uuid = new Uid(item.getId().toString());
event.getProperties().add(uuid);
```